# A rectangle in a rectangular hole

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

I have a carpet of 240 inches by 120 inches, but my floor, which it needs to cover, is 180 inches by 160 inches. How can I do this by cutting the carpet into exactly two pieces?

Source: Rational Amusement for Winter Evenings by John Jackson ([Google Books link](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=Fs42AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA26&dq=a+carpet+measures+20+feet+by+10+feet#v=onepage&q=a%20carpet%20measures%2020%20feet%20by%2010%20feet&f=false))

Comment: In simplest terms, scaling down by the common denominator of 20 (inches), the carpet is 12 x 6, and the hole is 9 x 8. Both have area 72.

Comment: I think a room of size 72 would be slightly less plausible, be that in ft^2, yd^2 or m^2.

Comment: @subdermatogylphic: I said scaled down; note that's why the resulting measurements (12x6 or 9x8) are unitless. They have no units.

Comment: @smci I know scaling down could be useful, but I meant that the exact numbers and units given are the most viable for posing a realistic question involving a carpet and a room without any need for me to edit the original puzzle much.

Comment: @subdermatogylphic: ok. Btw if you think 9 x 8 ft room is outlandish, see the trends towards 'tiny houses', 'microapartments' and adult dormitories in superheated property markets like SF...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scale is not consistent on the drawing:

> [image: Solution]

Answer (score 7):

> In addition to [trolley813](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21511/trolley813)'s two step cut, you can do a three-step cut to produce the same results rotated 90 degrees. Not precisely to scale:
>  [image]